# How can activate taxonomy field in content form on Drupal 6 ?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

*In my content type - > manage field i can see "Taxonomie--Taxonomy module form" field*
*In manage form - > i have also "taxonomie" and it's activate*

But when i want to edit or create content for this given content type, their is no option to select taxonomy, what i have missed ?

Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you do not have any terms in your vocabulary and hence there is nothing to select. Just check your taxonomy vocabulary if indeed you have terms there.

It is also possible that you chose the autotag widget instead of the select widget.

Whichever the case have a look at your content type and also the taxonomy vocabulary. It would be easier helping if the drupal version is known.